# Why am I getting two plots (instead of one) in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When using %matplotlib notebook I'm getting two plots instead of one from a pandas Series.

Code in cell is:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
cTitle='H-alpha plot '+galaxy[10:17]
cXAxisTitle='Galactocentric radius/pixels'
cYAxisTitle='Data counts'
ax1.set_title(cTitle)
ax1.set_xlabel(cXAxisTitle)
ax1.set_ylabel(cYAxisTitle)
ax1.grid()
ds.plot()
```

I'm getting Fig 1 and Fig 2:

[image]

[image]

Title, axis labels and grid lines in Fig 1 are what I want (expect) and plot in Fig 2 is also what I expect.  But why am I getting two plots anyway?

Comment: I suppose you would want to plot to the axes you have created previously, like `ds.plot(ax=ax)`.

Comment: You are spot on !!!  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start from:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**once**, at the beginning of your notebook.
My suggestion is to use *inline* instead of *notebook*.

Then run:

```
cTitle = 'H-alpha plot '+ galaxy[10:17]
cXAxisTitle = 'Galactocentric radius/pixels'
cYAxisTitle = 'Data counts'
ax1 = ds.plot(title=cTitle, grid=True)
ax1.set(xlabel=cXAxisTitle, ylabel=cYAxisTitle);
```

Note the semicolon at the end of the last instruction.
Otherwise you will have additional "messages" superimposed
on your drawing.